# How do I Replace Mythbuntu with 11.04 w/o Trashing SW Raid

Tags: installation, samba, uninstall, mythbuntu

I have a MythUbuntu server with a 14tb SW raid setup. I am finding Myth too finicky and would like to go to a vanilla Ubuntu install. Can someone direct me on the best way to approach this without trashing my Raid setup. I have a separate boot drive but am hesitant to proceed due to my newbie status and lack of experience with the raid aspects of the server.

Other than the fact I don't use any of the Myth features, the biggest problem I am having with the Myth setup is the one thing I do use and need - a Samba Share- will intermittently "disappear" from my network even though I have full network connectivity. It will mysteriously drop from the network and just as mysteriously show up anywhere from 10 minutes to 3 days later. This server has been operating for almost 2 years and just recently started acting screwy. No interaction, including rebooting, uninstalling/reinstalling Samba, recreating a new/replacement share, etc., seems to make any difference with these mystery actions. I have replaced the network card, ensured all updates are installed, and no one is interacting with the server when it disappears/reappears. I have 4 other Ubuntu servers and this is the only one having problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the standard Ubuntu desktop right into your Mythbuntu setup by doing

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then you may even choose to uninstall mythbuntu-related packages if you don't need them.

However, I don't think it'll solve your problems with Samba. For that, checking samba logs may give you some insights.

Comment: Sergey,
Thanks for the guidance. I have followed your directions and then the system asked if I wanted to upgrade to 10.10. I went ahead and upgraded, afterwhich it asked to upgrade to Natty. That is underway now. Natty install identified several missing "normal" packages that I agreed to install. Hopefully once this is all updated to Natty with the missing packages, I can get everything back to working correctly again. Thanks a bunch! I'll let you know the outcome.